# How to resolve this error with GeoServer Explorer Plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, boundless-suite, geoserver-explorer

This morning I changed my default password of geoserver and since then publishing layers or projects from QGIS not working using GeoServer Explorer Plugin. I am getting this error while trying to connect to Geoserver with the plugin:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/xyz/.qgis2/python/plugins\geoserverexplorer\gui\explorer.py", line 98, in run
        command(*params)
      File "C:/Users/xyz/.qgis2/python/plugins\geoserverexplorer\gui\gsexploreritems.py", line 534, in populate
        raise e
    FailedRequestError
```

I have changed the password to default again.  Reinstalled Geoserver to overwrite the securities and reinstalled QGIS (by deleting the OSGeo4W64 Directory) and deleted the local .qgis2 folder. At one moment I was not even able to see Workspace directories but I am still getting the above error upon connecting . I can add WMS from geoserver to my QGIS project but I can not publish the layer or project from QGIS. 
Versions: 
QGIS : 2.14.1 Essen
GeoServer explorer Plugin: 0.1.1
Geoserver: 2.8.2

Comment: Can you log in to GeoServer?

What about you set up a new connection from the QGIS Plugin, and make sure you're pointed at the right server location and using the right UN/PW.

Comment: Yes- I can login. I can create new connection and checked connection many times but results are still the same.

Comment: What's the URL you're using to connect to GeoServer?

Comment: http://localhost:3301/geoserver or with server name replacing localhost

Comment: Seems reasonable. You're including http:// right?

Answer (score 1):

If you still didn't fix your problem, then maybe this might help you:

Try to check if all data stores you have are valid (so their sources are available). I had data stores added via Geoserver Web Interface to which I had manually deleted source shp files from the server hdd. So the Geoserver data stores were invalid and the source destinations were pointing into not existing files. And until I didn't delete those data stores that were no longer needed, the Geoserver Explorer plugin was throwing errors and I had the python warning log present right after connecting to my Geoserver. I still could somehow work with WMS and layers that managed to load via the Geoserver Explorer plugin though.

Maybe you accidentally deleted some data sources or due to the password change, some privileges changed and your local Geoserver instance (or QGIS + GE plugin) can't access data and started to throw errors/warnings.